# Creating variable array for keycode

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a single variable that contains all of the function key codes. If I remove the brackets and use a single keycode everything works.

```
$('input').keyup(function (e) {

    var functionKeysPressed = e.which == [114, 115, 116, etc];

    if (!functionKeysPressed) {

    }

});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [**indexOf()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

```
$('input').keyup(function (e) {

    var functionKeysPressed = [114, 115, 116, etc].indexOf(e.which) > -1;

    if (!functionKeysPressed) {

    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if element exist in array you should use `indexOf`

```
function contains(e) {    
    return [114, 115, 116, etc].indexOf(e.which) != -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `indexOf` to see if that is existing:

```
[114, 115, 116, etc].indexOf(e.which) != -1
```

So your code becomes:

```
$('input').keyup(function (e) {
    var functionKeysPressed = [114, 115, 116, etc].indexOf(e.which) != -1;
    if (!functionKeysPressed) {

    }
});
```